# .htaccess is creating a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am creating a test site and all I have is a .htaccess file at root level along with my index.html and all that has is "hello world". All I have in my .htcacess is:

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "restricted area"  
AuthUserFile /PasswordProtected/.htpasswd  
require valid-user
```

This is throwing up a 500 Internal Server Error and it goes if i remove the .htaccess file.

Comment: Check your Apache error.log for 500 error.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, I'm not sure how to do that. Is it something I can check in Chrome's developer tools?

Comment: @SaturnsEye No - your browser is only seeing an error raised by Apache. You'll need to dig into your Apache error logging to find the issue, but the location of that log can vary depending upon your installation.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I may sound stupid but how do I do that? My files are uploaded using FileZilla to the FTP location. How do I access Apache?

Comment: @SaturnsEye If you're using a third party to do your hosting, that'll be a question for them.

Comment: All you have is your `.htaccess` file at root level? What about the directory that goes through to your `.htpasswd`?

Comment: I *suspect* that your problem may be the `AuthUserFile` setting though, as the path should be absolute on the server itself (e.g. /var/www/...)

Comment: @thickguru The .htpasswd files is in the correct folder to what the .htaccess is pointed at.

Comment: and the layout of your `.htpasswd` file looks similar to this: `example:mYpAs5w0rd`

Comment: @thickguru Yep "username:password"

Comment: Ultimately, you need to contact your provider, to get the log, to view the error message. Everything else is guesswork, sorry.

Comment: Make sure your password file has no write permission for group and others.